# Can't boot home server running CentOS 8 - Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, boot, centos, grub, kernel-panic

After about 1 year uptime, my home server running CentOS 8 as a parent and two KVM machines also running CentOS 8 and hosting Nextcloud, pihole, an NFS share and some other small services was not reachable anymore. So I killed it and tried to start again. But the machine does not boot and no advice I found online helped so far.

This is what's displayed when trying to boot (ommitting the timestamps, since I am typing this) :

```
[drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_hander [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO undrrun
[drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_undrrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[drm:cpt_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata2.00: cmd 60/20:a0:d0:c9:d3/00:00:0a:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 16384 in
         res 41/40:00:d0:c9:d3/00:00:0a:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata2.00: error: { UNC }
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 181651920 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: systemd Not tainted 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 7010/0GY6Y8, BIOS A16 09/09/2013
Call Trace:
 dump_stack+0x5c/0x80
 panic+0xe7/0x2a9
 do_exit.cold.22+0x59/0x81
 ? __fput+0x154/0x230
 do_group_exit+0x3a/0xa0
 __x64_sys_exit_group+0x14/0x20
 do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x1a0
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x65/0xca
RIP: 0033:0x7ff23763648e
Code: Bad RIP value.
RSP: 002b:00007ffd2630b5f8 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
(some more numbers)
Kernel Offset: 0x26200000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: numbers-numbers)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
 ]---
```

I hope there are no typos.

The system was running the 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2 Kernel, booting in UEFI mode and I am pretty sure I successfully tested a system restart before I let it run for such a prolonged period of time.

What I tried until now:

1. Try to boot into the other installed Kernels. Different Kernels show different error messages, all ending in the same line.
2. Disable SELinux by setting both `SELINUX` and `SELINUXTYPE` in `/etc/selinux/config` to `disabled`. This does nothing.
3. Disable Virtualization in BIOS. Also does nothing.
4. Reinstall the bootloader. I am not able to do this, because of the following:

When trying to chroot from the anaconda rescue mode as per [the documentation to reinstall GRUB](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/#sect-rescue-reinstall-grub2) or by executing `chroot /mnt/sysroot` as suggested by the anaconda console itself, i get following error:

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I understand by now, that the error `ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA` may indicate that the disk is broken. I am trying to do a backup now. Is this the right step? If yes, can I clone the disk 1:1 and then boot from a new one as if nothing ever happened? How would you proceed?

Maybe somebody can guide me a bit. Quite some people rely on the services hosted by this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata2.00: cmd 60/20:a0:d0:c9:d3/00:00:0a:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 16384 in
         res 41/40:00:d0:c9:d3/00:00:0a:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata2.00: error: { UNC }
```

You seem to have lost your hard disk. Looks like bad blocks or something similar. Try connecting it to another SATA port using a known good cable just to be certain, but probably you'll need to get a new disk. You can try to salvage what can be salvaged from the faulty disk using a utility like `testdisk` afterwards. In the case of SSDs, data recovery will probably not yield anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I can mount the root and boot partitions from a live usb. I guess I will be able to recover at least some of the data, if this is the faulty disk. How do I find that out? Does ata2.00 mean that it's the disk connected to the physical Sata2 port on the mainboard?

Comment: Normally yes, this should be on SATA2

Comment: I backed up the drive, and everything seems fine with the backup. When I do a selftest now, the test result is PASSED. It still does not boot. Maybe there are just files missing?

Comment: Before panicking it has this line: `blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 181651920 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0`. It cannot read a specific disk sector (181651920). This means most probably a failing disk. When sectors start to become unreadable it usually goes south. I would put that disk to rest.